# How to build chatbot using botkit anywhere in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, botkit

I am trying to build a chatbot using botkit anywhere and nodejs. I don't want to use any third-party messaging platform. I refer to this link https://github.com/howdyai/botkit#build-your-bot and try to setup chatbot in nodejs application:

> First, add it to your project:
>
> npm install --save botkit
>
> Then, add Botkit to your application code:
>
> var Botkit = require('botkit');
>
> var controller = Botkit.anywhere(configuration);
>
> controller.hears('hello','direct_message', function(bot, message) {
>       bot.reply(message,'Hello yourself!'); });

But they don't mention how to call and where to call this code in the existing application.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start you need a NLU middle ware. Since you don't want to use 3rd party services, you can use RASA NLU and Botkit has easy integration too.

https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu

Then You can the below easy to use Botkit-Anywhere-RASA library.

https://github.com/matteoredaelli/botkit-starter-web-rasa-nlu

1) Star the RASA NLU server

2) Clone the starter project (#2) and run using "node ."

Answer (score 0):

For Botkit Web anywhere:
I followed following URL steps:
https://botkit.ai/getstarted.html

after these steps my folder structure is like below:

[image]

you can navigate to public->client.js and here you can find method.